# Changing GridView Item height using VSM Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview

I'm currently working on a WPF application, and I have a GridView displaying items from a pre-populated collection:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridContainer" ... ItemsSource="{Binding ProfItemCollection}">
      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <local:ProfItem />
          </DataTemplate>
     </GridView.ItemTemplate>         
</GridView>
```

I also have a Visual State Manager which has triggers based on the window size:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="300" MinWindowHeight="300"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                ...
                ...
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        ...
        ...
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I would like to ***change the GridView Item Height from within these visual states***.  I'm having trouble doing this...I know I can change the height by doing the following within the GridView Control:

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

However, I can't figure out how to change this property value from within a VisualState Setter.  I've tried attaching an `x:Name` property to the Setter in the code above, but it doesn't work when I reference this name in a VisualState Setter.

Is there a way to make this work in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used the VSM, but have you tried declaring the various styles you need to switch between as resources, and assign the style of the GridView to the correct resource in the setter?

```
<!-- In resources section -->
<Style x:Key="smallGVStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="mediumGVStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="300" />
</Style>

<!-- VSM -->
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="300" MinWindowHeight="300"/>
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter TargetName="GridContainer" Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=smallGVStyle}"/>                ...
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        ...
        ...
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Perfect solution, I didn't think of having multiple styles